# How can I use both networks simultaneously

Tags: route

I have two network interfaces: eth0 (10.0.0.0) and usb0 (umts usb-modem)

```
me@ThinkCentre-A50:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.41.250.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
```

How can I use both networks simultaneously. Go Internet (www) via usb0, and connect to the local network via the eth0?

Comment: What system do you use?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10

Comment: How did you configure your network interfaces? `dhclient` or via `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 0):

You actually can ! All you must do is make sure you use the usb-modem as DEFAULT gateway, and let it NAT (in fact this is PAT) your local address to its globally routed address.
The gateway can be set with

```
 route add default gw 192.168.42.X
```

where X is the local ip-address of the usb-modem. Local 10.41.250.1-126 Addresses will then go via eth0, the rest via the default gateway.

I cannot tell you how to configure the umts-modem, since i don't know anything about it.

Maybe you need an additional daemon (pppd) bound to it, which then will handle setting up the connection and addresses. As soon as you have an ip-connection on the usb port, you will be able to "masquerade" local addresses with "iptables" or similar.

Comment: me@ThinkCentre-A50:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.42.113 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Answer (score 0):

First, the machine accesses networks through its interfaces. Often one says "the IP address of the machine is...", but that is incorrect, an IP address belongs to an interface. And it is even possible to assign several IP addresses to the same network card. As most machines have just one interface with one IP address, this *usually* causes no confusion, but complicates things when several interfaces/addresses are involved. Better don't do this.

If the default gateway is set through the USB interface, *all* traffic that doesn't go to the network(s) connected directly to the other interface(s) will go through it. Unless you go *seriously* out of your way, you have no say on which interface is used.

If you want other machines on the 10.0.0.0 (internal) network to be able to access the outer net, you have to set up this machine as a router, and by the way NAT (really PAT) the internal addresses through the outer one. Read up on setting up a firewall in Ubuntu. There are probably GUI applications for doing this, as I've never used Ubuntu (and I'm allergic to GUIs), I can't help there. Presumably your "external" 192.168.42.0 address is configured by DHCP, and I've never set up a firewall in such a case either, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete default routes

   - `route del 0/0`
2. Add LAN route to go over eth0

   - `route add net 10.41.250.0/25 gw 10.41.250.1 eth0`
3. Add default route to go over usb0

   - `route add default 192.168.42.1 usb0`

This assumes that your LAN gateway has the IP address of 10.41.250.1, while your WAN gateway has the IP address of 192.168.42.1.